# Decode base64 + decrypt - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, swift2

```
let originalMsg:String = "THIS IS A TEST"
let sessionData = originalMsg.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)        
var encryptedPublic:NSData = RNCryptor.encryptData(sessionData!, password: ProjectConstants.MessageEncrypt.PUBLIC_KEY)
var base64EncodedPublic:NSData = encryptedPublic.base64EncodedDataWithOptions([])
var encryptedPrivate = RNCryptor.encryptData(base64EncodedPublic, password: privateKey)
var base64EncodedString:String = encryptedPrivate.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
```

How would you decode + decrypt base64EncodedString to get the original input? I think I am struggling with the base64 decoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you get a UTF-8 encoded `NSString` from a base64 string in Swift 2:

```
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64EncodedString,
                         options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)
let decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

But if you want to decrypt, you'll just want the data:

```
do {
    let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64EncodedString,
                         options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)
    let decryptedPrivate = RNDecryptor.decryptData(decodedData, password: privateKey)
    let decodedPrivate = NSData(base64EncodedData: decryptedPrivate,
                            options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)
    let decryptedPublic = RNDecryptor.decryptData(decodedPrivate, password: ProjectConstants.MessageEncrypt.PUBLIC_KEY)
    let decryptedMessage = NSString(data: decryptedPublic, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String
} catch {
  // handle decryption errors...
}
```